# Prove that $\sqrt{1+\pi^2}, \hspace{2pt}\pi-\sqrt\pi,\hspace{2pt} \pi^2+\pi+\sqrt{1+2\pi}$ are not algebraic

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Considering the fact that $\pi$ is not an algebraic number, I need to prove these expressions are not algebraic :

$$\sqrt{1+\pi^2},\hspace{10pt} \pi-\sqrt\pi,\hspace{10pt} \pi^2+\pi+\sqrt{1+2\pi}$$

Thanks

Some explanations will be appreciated ! Thank you all for your time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $c=\pi^2+\pi+\sqrt{1+2\pi}$. Then

$$
\sqrt{1+2\pi}=c-\pi^2-\pi
$$
and
$$
1+2\pi=(c-\pi^2-\pi)^2
$$
and, rearranging terms, you get a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}[c]$ that is satisfied by $\pi$. This means that $\pi$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}[c]$. But you know that $\pi$ is transcendental, so also $c$ must be transcendental, otherwise you'd get that
$$
[\mathbb{Q}[\pi]:\mathbb{Q}]=
[\mathbb{Q}[\pi]:\mathbb{Q}[c]][\mathbb{Q}[c]:\mathbb{Q}]
$$
would be finite.

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha_1$ is algebraic, then so is $\alpha_1^2-1$.

If $\alpha_2$ is algebraic, then so is $\left(\sqrt{\alpha_2+\frac14}+\frac12\right)^2$.

Can you see a similar reason for $\alpha_3$?

Comment: Thank you dear Hagen, but I don't understand the idea behind your response ... Would give me some extra explanations? Thanks!

Comment: If $\alpha_1=\sqrt{1+\pi^2}$, what is $\alpha_1^2-1$? Is that algebraic or transcendental?

Comment: is Pi^2 which from the start is algebraic , right ?

Comment: If $\pi$ is not algebraic then $\pi^2$ is not algebraic.

Comment: Sorry, : - ) I think in my head at not algebraic ... but I type algebraic, my bad

Comment: So, if I obtain after some calculations something not algebraic from alfa 1, alfa 2, alfa 3, then all these are not algebraic?

Comment: For the third case, I can not see a similar reason ...